How is ' chastise for iniquity ' in 2 Sam 7: 14 explained?
We read in 2 Sam 7: 12-14 (KJV), of the promise that God makes to David through Prophet Nathan:

And when thy days be fulfilled, and thou shalt sleep with thy fathers, I will set up thy seed after thee, which shall proceed out of thy bowels, and I will establish his kingdom.He shall build an house for my name, and I will stablish the throne of his kingdom for ever.I will be his father, and he shall be my son. If he commit iniquity, I will chasten him with the rod of men, and with the stripes of the children of men.

Jesus is  called Son of David throughout the Gospels. Nathan's above said prophecy is also said to have been fulfilled in Jesus. But a doubt remains as to what is meant by 'chastising for  iniquity' if the prophecy was exclusively on Jesus ? How do Bible scholars explain the phrase ?
